# CSS3, display flex. Иерархия. Вложеные флексы

Tags: html, css3, flexbox

Пример кода:

```css
.flex-container-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<main class="flex-container-column">
  <div>
    <div class="flex-container-row">
      <div><img src="img/cheez.jpg"> </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Teste our cheesburger just for 4.99$</h2>
        <p>Something about cheesburger</p>
      </div>

    </div>
```

На моменте

```
<div class="flex-container-row">
```

блоки не выстраиваются в ряд.

Что не так?
Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выстраиваются. Добавил подсветку фона.

```css
.flex-container-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-container-row > :first-child {
  background: blue;
}

.flex-container-row > :first-child + * {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<main class="flex-container-column">
  <div>
    <div class="flex-container-row">
      <div><img src="img/cheez.jpg"> </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Teste our cheesburger just for 4.99$</h2>
        <p>Something about cheesburger</p>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Чудеса да и только! 
Спасибо